# Jquery mobile, twitter search loading

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, twitter, cordova

I'm very new at this still but I'm trying to get into jQuery mobile.

This part of my app (just to test things out on) is to load different twitter search queries based on clicking 1 of 2 buttons. So in order to change the query I was thinking of passing the data-identity text and concatenating it with the rest of the search string.

So I've made a start and I think I know where I'm wrong but I don't know how to go about doing it right really!

Essentially what I think is going wrong is that the twitter search is loaded immediately into the page but my string is only passed after the user clicks a button (with class twitterlink on it). So firstly I can't get the variable passing out but secondly the tweets won't load because the url: isn't filled at the time it should be.

So when I hardcode //var url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:irishhockey'; it works grand but trying to do anykind of variable stuff just isn't working for me at the moment

```
    var twitId;
     var url;   

    $(function(){

    //this part is to grab the data-identity string in       
     $('.twitterlink').live('click', 
                      function() {
                         twitId = $(this).data("identity");
                    //this was to concatenate the first part of the string with the twitId (data-identity)
                       url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:' + twitId ;

                      }
                );
    //with the below hardcoded line uncommented it brings tweets in fine
    //var url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:irishhockey';

       $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json_results){

                console.log(json_results);

                // Need to add UL on AJAX call or formatting of userlist is not displayed
                $('#twitList').append('<ul data-role="listview"></ul>');
                listItems = $('#twitList').find('ul');
                $.each(json_results.results, function(key) {
                    html = '<img src="'+json_results.results[key].profile_image_url+'"/>';
                    html += '<h3><a href="#">'+json_results.results[key].text+'</a></h3>';
                    html += '<p>From: '+json_results.results[key].from_user+' Created: '+json_results.results[key].created_at+'</p>';
                    listItems.append('<li>'+html+'</li>');
                });
                // Need to refresh list after AJAX call
                $('#twitList ul').listview();

            }
        })
    })
```

I tried putting it all into the one click function aswell, hoping it didn't fire off the ajax stuff immediately but that didn't work either for me.

I know I'm probably just approaching this in all the wrong way but I'm just not sure what way I should be going at it, so as I say.. all help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to sort this guys, I took the data-identity grabber out of the function, wasn't needed and it seems to be working ok now (tidying needed of course, but other than that!)
cheers anyway

```
var twitId;
var url;

$('.twitterlink').live('click', function() {
    twitId = $(this).data("identity");
    url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:' + twitId;


$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json_results) {

        console.log(json_results);


        // Need to add UL on AJAX call or formatting of userlist is not displayed
        $('#twitList').append('<ul data-role="listview"></ul>');
        listItems = $('#twitList').find('ul');
        $.each(json_results.results, function(key) {
            html = '<img src="' + json_results.results[key].profile_image_url + '"/>';
            html += '<h3><a href="#">' + json_results.results[key].text + '</a></h3>';
            html += '<p>From: ' + json_results.results[key].from_user + ' Created: ' + json_results.results[key].created_at + '</p>';
            listItems.append('<li>' + html + '</li>');
        });
        // Need to refresh list after AJAX call
        $('#twitList ul').listview();


        }
    })
})
```